# Android работа с WSDL

Tags: android, xml

Есть веб-сервер с которым работают при помощи WSDL. Решили к нему написать android-приложение.

До этого мне не приходилось работать с WSDL. Гугл я прочитал и общее представление о нем получил. Но все еще не представляю как с ним работать. Возможно есть какая-то библиотека(еще не нашел сам) которая упрощает жизнь, если вы сталкивались то не могли бы хотя бы название подсказать. Или если у вас есть исходники работы с WDSL на gitHub, это было бы тоже неплохим подспорьем.

Кратка формулируя вопрос: как работать с WDSL на Android?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, `WSDL` - это внутренний стандарт сервера, который никак не влияет на способ работы с сервером. Это скорее всего обычный `REST`- сервис, и работать с ним нужно так же.

Comment: То есть работа сводится к "гонянию" http-запросов и получению xml файлов с последующим их парсингом, опираясь на некий файл xml,который мы используем как словарь для работы в текущей сессии приложения?

Comment: Нет, я ошибся, не все так, как я думал. Вот нашел пример:http://www.wsdl2code.com/Pages/Example.aspx

Comment: "Гугл я прочитал" - чертовски сильно сказано. Извините, не сдержался :)

Comment: @jangorussia сделайте "продолжение" новым вопросом.

Comment: @zRrr я могу создать отдельный вопрос, но ответ на него я уже имею. Создавать вопрос на который я сам и отвечу - не вижу смысла.

Comment: @jangorussia откатите последнюю правку вопроса тогда, а то получается, что ответы даны, один принят, но вопрос им не соответствует.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WDSL` это просто язык описания веб-служб, как правило SOAP-сервисов.
Когда-то я использовал вот эту библиотеку для работы с SOAP на Андроид.
http://simpligility.github.io/ksoap2-android/index.html

Все работало как надо, копайте в эту сторону.

Comment: До ксопа добрался, но 1сник не может обьяснить как мне авторизоваться, ибо запрос без авторизации никак. Если разберусь,то этот ответ сойдет за верный

Comment: Пример авторизации через заголовки:  
*StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("login");
            buffer.append(':').append("password");
            byte[] bytes = buffer.toString().getBytes();
            buffer.setLength(0);
            buffer.append("Basic ");
            org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode(bytes, 0, bytes.length, buffer);
            List<HeaderProperty> headers = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
            headers.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", buffer.toString()));
...
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope,headers);*

Comment: Это Basic Authentication https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2617#section-2  
В этом случае важно, чтобы все запросы шли по HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

В Android своего WSDL клиента нету. но можно использовать клиент

[ksoap2-android](http://simpligility.github.io/ksoap2-android/index.html)

Лицензия MIT.

Maven библиотеки

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.ksoap2-android</groupId>
      <artifactId>ksoap2-android</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>ossrh</id>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.ksoap2-android</groupId>
      <artifactId>ksoap2-extra-ntlm</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

---

Так же нашел библиотеку [Wsdl2Code генератор](http://www.wsdl2code.com/Pages/Example.aspx)а `java` класса из `WSDL` данных

Пример:

Используется так:

```
    public void callWebService(){ 
     SampleService srv1 = new SampleService();
     req = new Request();                     
     req.companyId = "1";
     req.userName = "userName";                                     
     req.password = "pas";
     Response response =    srv1.ServiceSample(req);
}
```

Привет автоматически сгенерированного кода

```
package com.Wsdl2Code.WebServices.SampleService;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import java.util.Date;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.HeaderProperty;
import java.util.List;

public class SampleService{
    public String NAMESPACE =" http://Wsdl2CodeTestService/";
    public String url="{0}";
    public int timeOut = 60000;



    public void setTimeOut(int seconds){
        this.timeOut = seconds * 1000;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }
    public String HelloWorld(){
        return HelloWorld(null);
    }


    public String HelloWorld(List<HeaderProperty> headers){

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.implicitTypes = true;
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        SoapObject soapReq = new SoapObject("http://Wsdl2CodeTestService/","HelloWorld");

        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapReq);
        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url,timeOut);
        try{

            if (headers!=null){
                httpTransport.call("http://Wsdl2CodeTestService/HelloWorld", soapEnvelope,headers);
            }else{
                httpTransport.call("http://Wsdl2CodeTestService/HelloWorld", soapEnvelope);
            }
            SoapObject result=(SoapObject)soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Response ServiceSample(Request req){
        return ServiceSample(req,null);
    }


    public Response ServiceSample(Request req,List<HeaderProperty> headers){

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.implicitTypes = true;
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        SoapObject soapReq = new SoapObject("http://Wsdl2CodeTestService","ServiceSample");
        soapEnvelope.addMapping("http://Wsdl2CodeTestService","Response",new Response().getClass());
        soapEnvelope.addMapping("http://Wsdl2CodeTestService","req",new Request().getClass());
        soapReq.addProperty("req",req);

        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapReq);
        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url,timeOut);
        try{

            if (headers!=null){
                httpTransport.call("http://Wsdl2CodeTestService/ServiceSample", soapEnvelope,headers);
            }else{
                httpTransport.call("http://Wsdl2CodeTestService/ServiceSample", soapEnvelope);
            }
            SoapObject result=(SoapObject)soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
            SoapObject soapObject =(SoapObject) result.getPropertySafely("ServiceSampleResult");
            Response ServiceSampleResult = new Response(soapObject);
            return ServiceSampleResult;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```